# JavaScript delay between functions using setTimeout(function, delay)

Tags: javascript, delay, settimeout

I want my program to be executed with delay between each execution. Now I have this:

```
function function0() {
    setTimeout(function1, 3000);
    setTimeout(function2, 3000);
    setTimeout(function0, 3000);
}
```

There is delay between each execution of function0 but not between function1 and funtion2, function2 is run immediately after function1. How do I solve this?

Comment: What in the world are you trying to do? That code just runs each function 3 seconds later...

Comment: `setTimeout` is non-blocking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not elegant, but it should work.. At the end of function 2, function 1 will be execute around 3 seconds later, same between function 1 and loop function.

```
function function0() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // <my_function2>

        setTimeout(function() {
            // <my_function1>

            setTimeout(function0, 3000);
        }, 3000);
    }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All functions are executed after 3 seconds. Did you mean to do this:

```
function function0() {
    setTimeout(function1, 3000);
    setTimeout(function2, 6000);
    setTimeout(function0, 9000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` is non blocking, so all three of those functions will run after 3 seconds. Changing it to something like this:

```
function function0() {
    setTimeout(function1, 3000);
    setTimeout(function2, 6000);
    setTimeout(function0, 9000);
}
```

Will cause them each to run 3 seconds apart. If you didn't want to hardcode this, you could use `setInterval`, increment the function name (since your functions have numbers to distinguish between them), then stop after x amount of iterations:

```
var i = 0,
int = setInterval(function () {
    // Function logic
    i++;
    if (i === 3) {
        clearInterval(int);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do this:

```
function function0() {
    setTimeout(function1, 3000);
}
function function1() {
    /*
     Your code here
     */
    setTimeout(function2, 3000);
}
function function2() {
    /*
     Your code here
     */
    setTimeout(function3, 3000);
}
function function3() {
    /*
     Your code here
     */
}
```